# How to disable caching of routes.rb for tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, minitest

I noticed that when I change `routes.rb` so that something is supposed to break, Minitest continues to use my previous version of the file, so the tests pass when they shouldn't. To update it I have to either put `Rails.application.reload_routes!` into the test code, or run `rails routes` in console after each modification of `routes.rb`.

Is there a way to avoid doing this and just auto-reload routes on each test?

**P.S:** If it's relevant, what I do are exercises to M.Hartl's tutorial, chapter 5.3.2 https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-exercises_rails_routes

Comment: How do you change the routes between tests? Do you mean between two runs of the whole test suite or between two examples?

Comment: 1) $ rails t -> tests pass,
2) edit routes.rb to break smth.,
3) $ rails t -> tests pass,
4) $ rails routes -> shows updated routes table,
5) $ rails t -> tests fail.

Same way when I revert changes to routes.rb

Comment: Do you use spring? I bet it's the culprit.

Comment: Could you check output of this command:

`$ bin/spring status`

If this is running, try this

`$ bin/spring stop`

Comment: It was indeed Spring's fault, thanks all!

Comment: Shouldn't Spring by default watch for changes in `routes.rb`?

Comment: @Froschgesicht: I think it does watch, but sometimes it just fails to reload. Because reasons...